# How to divide time (chrono) by a given value

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I'm working on getting familiar with chrono to evaluate performance.  I have a global variable in which it collects time inserting words from a file to a vector of strings.  If I have n strings inserted, how do I divide that time by n to get the average time and convert it to seconds, microseconds, milliseconds? I found how to divide a chrono time by another chrono but cant find how to divide by a given number n. Here is what I have attempted:

```
//global var
auto InsertionTimerChainingHT = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
//... function declerations
// inside function where I insert strings to vector
auto total = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
for (auto it = DataArray.begin(); it != DataArray.end(); it++)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    ChainingHT.insert(it->data());
    auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    total += (stop - start);


}
InsertionTimerChainingHT = total;
// I attempted to do the following
InsertionTimerChainingHT /= 1853;
InsertionTimerChainingHT = (InsertionTimerChainingHT / 1853).count();
```

Comment: Use `std::chrono::duration<double> diff = start - stop;` to get the time in seconds. Why do you divide by 1853?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks for letting me know how to convert in secounds. 
1853 is the amount of items I have inserted within the given time span.  I am trying to get the average time for strings inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your `total` as a `chrono::duration`, not a `chrono::time_point`.  The return of `system_clock::now()` is a `time_point` (an instant in time).  The difference between `stop` and `start` is a `duration` (like 3 microseconds).

For example:

```
auto total = std::chrono::system_clock::duration{0};  // zero system_clock ticks
```

`duration` can be divided by a scalar, resulting in a `duration`:

```
total /= DataArray.size();
```

Comment: Glad it worked out.  If you've got an hour, here's the video tutorial for chrono: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M